# Angular: linking transcluded templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, transclusion

I have a directive that is populated partially by an ng-repeat from the parent scope and then listeners are attached in `postLink`. However, because the content is transcluded, it is not available/interpolated by link-time.

I've thrown together a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pnQyA/7/) to demonstrate:

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="directive.html">
        <div>list item count: {{ count }} (should be {{2 + items.length }})</div>
        <div>Transcluded content: <span ng-transclude></span></div>
</script>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <ul frag>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{ item }}</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
app.directive("frag", function ($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.count = element.find("li").length;
            console.log(element);
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.foundB = false;
        }
    };
});
```

In this case, the list item count ends up as 2 rather than the expected 5 one would expect post-transclusion.

Anyone have any ideas how I could make this work? Was expecting to find some sort of post-transclude event that I could observe and only do the linking then, but not been able to find one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$timeout` to move the code to the end of the execution queue, after the digest cycle:

```
app.directive("frag", function ($http, $timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'directive.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                scope.count = element.find("li").length;
            });
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $element) {
            $scope.foundB = false;
        }
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pnQyA/8/

Comment: Ta - I had been saving using `$timeout` as a last resort though! Hoping either (a) I'd missed something obvious, or (b) there's something neater.